# Implementing Exit button in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to implement an exit button, but I'm unable to use `connect()` method to do this. Actually my button does not emit any signal as far as I know, but I can't find the problem.
Here is part of my code that uses `connect()` method:

```
#include "MyMainWindow.h"

MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags flag) :
        QMainWindow(parent, flag)
{
    this->setFixedSize(1120, 630);
    menu = new MyMenu(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(menu);
    this->show();
    // the connect implementation
    connect(menu->exit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(this->exit_button_clicked()));
}

MyMainWindow::~MyMainWindow()
{
}

void MyMainWindow::exit_button_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

`MyMainWindow` is a friend class of `MyMenu` and `exit` is a private `QPushButton`. Now I want some help for solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as below directly

```
connect(menu->exit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
```

There is no need to create new method `exit_button_clicked()` as `SLOT`

Answer (score 2):

`SLOT` is a macro that actually accepts a string rather than a c++-valid expression.

`SLOT(this->exit_button_clicked())` will not be linked to a correct slot. You need to write `SLOT(exit_button_clicked())` instead. Qt Creator's auto-complete can suggest valid slots for selected objects.

A recommented alternative is to use [new syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#New_Signal_Slot_Syntax_in_Qt_5). You can use it in Qt 5 if your compiler supports C++11. The advantage of this syntax is compile-time check of signals, slots and their arguments.

If `menu->exit` is private, you can't access it from another class unless it's declared as a `friend class`. You may need to create a public getter in `MyMenu` class.

Comment: thank you, but non of these methods are working. the first solution does compile but does not call the desired method, and the second one gives me compile error (Clion markes it as red). here is my changed `connect()` method: `connect(menu->exit, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyMainWindow::exit_button_clicked);` is this the correct implementation??

Comment: Is `menu->exit` a `QPushButton`?

Comment: What is the compiler message?

Comment: paste your class definition for MyMainWindow. Something about your inheritance from QMainWindow etc isn't right, as per the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is a solution that doesn't use lambdas, for simple actions lambdas work great:

```
connect(menu->exit, &QPushButton::clicked(), [&this]{ exit_button_clicked(); });
```

It's quite nice when the actual syntax to do something is so close to your expectation of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont make a hard code make it simple. Just go to your UI and locate the button
and right click it then select go to slots then select

> clicked()

then just write

> close();

It should look like this

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


//This is the slot of the button exit
void MainWindow::on_quit_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```